# MarkLogic globally unique URIs

Tags: uri, unique, marklogic

During the mlcp import of aggregate XML file `/space/data/big.xml`, the default document URI will be like `/space/data/big.xml-0-1` `/space/data/big.xml-0-2`, etc.

Since there is no unique tag value to use `-uri_id` in the document and generated above URIs are not globally unique, is there any option to get unique URIs (i.e. like for RDF `c7f92bccb4e2bfdc-0-100.xml`)?

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a [custom transformation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_82518) module and then construct a URI that concatenates a random value using functions such as [`sem.uuidString()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/sem.uuidString).

```
function envelope(content, context)
{
  content.uri = sem.uuidString() + "-" + content.uri;
  return content;
};
exports.transform = envelope;
```

[Using a Custom Transformation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_36783)

> Once you install a custom transformation function on MarkLogic Server, you can apply it to your mlcp import or copy job using the following options:
>
> `-transform_module` - The path to the module containing your transformation.

```
$ mlcp.sh import -mode local -host mlhost -port 8000 \
    -username user -password password \
    -input_file_path /space/mlcp-test/data \
    -transform_module /example/mlcp-transform.sjs
```

Comment: Ok, Mads, thanks for your answer!